# About bounding the "proportion" of a binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there some explicit examples of functions $f,g:(0,1/2]\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(\delta)\leq\dbinom{n}{\lfloor\delta n\rfloor}\leq g(\delta)$ for all natural $n$ (or at least for all $n\geq N_0$ for an explicit $N_0$)?